# R - Creating average of auto.arima and ets forecasts?

Tags: r, forecasting

I have one time series that I forecast with ets() and auto.arima() from the forecast package.
Now I want to create an average of the forecasted values. The code below works, but it is not very nice. For instance I cant automatically plot the results similar to an ets or auto.arima forecast. I need to manually recreate a similar chart.

Maybe someone has a better approach?

Thanks a lot!

```
## auto.arima and ets forecasts
require(forecast)
myactuals <- c(1:36)
myts <- ts(myactuals, start=2011, frequency=12)
myarima <- auto.arima(myts)  
myets <- ets(myts)
myarimaforecast <- forecast(myarima, h=12)
myetsforecast <- forecast(myets, h=12)

## merge the two forecasts
mycomposite <- NULL
mycomposite$x <- myts
mycomposite$mean <- (myarimaforecast$mean + myetsforecast$mean)/2
```

Comment: Is this R? If so, you might want to edit the tags of your question so it gets more attention. Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you Seanny123! Yes, this is R. I have just added the tag :-)

Comment: Do you still need this answered?